# _io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name' for small size file

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload, temporary-files, bytesio

I'm uploading file with python/Django and getting two different object. When file is small in size, getting `InMemoryUploadedFile` object,  while file is quite large, i got in `temporaryFileWrapper`.  I m checking file mime type with `magic` library.

when File is large, getting correct`mime type` with this code

```
file_name = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
file_mime= magic.from_file(file_name.file.name, mime=True)

supported_format= ['video/x-flv','video/mp4','video/3gpp','video/x-ms-wmv']
 if file_mime  in supported_format:
    ...........
```

But when file is small in size  i m getting error

`_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name`

For large file

[image]

For small file

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have changed the type of the `file`. In the first example it is a file writer, in the second a `bytesIO` object. So I think the first call apparently has some side-effects.

Comment: Nope, In both case file type are same. only size is different.

Comment: it's not the *file type*. In fact a file has no type at all, I mean the *object type* is different. So that means something looks wrong with the program that performs import. It either has side-effects, or the `magic` library has no contracts on what the output type is.

Comment: yes, i m also confused, why  `object type` is different while file are same.

Comment: @Akhilendra yadav Can you add a ***re-producible*** snippet for the same?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, problem solved,  Actually Django `UploadedFile` have two subclasses `TemporaryUploadedFile`  for  large files and `InMemoryUploadedFile`  for small file. I set default `TemporaryUploadedFile`. See docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#module-django.core.files.uploadhandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Django's [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#module-django.core.files.uploadhandler), Django have two upload file handler  `MemoryFileUploadHandler` and `TemporaryFileUploadHandler`. 
`MemoryFileUploadHandler` stream to memory , and  `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` stream to disk.

I have set deafult `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` im my `setting.py`

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS= ["django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler"]
```

We can also write own custom `FileUploadHandler` in django